# R Language: How to use Specan function on my own wav file?

Tags: r

I am trying to use `specan` function from [`warbleR`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/warbleR/index.html) package. I want to pass my own wav file as an argument to the function. I have seen only one example in docs which is not much self explanatory.

```
wave_file <- readWave("C:/Users/ABC/Downloads/file_example_WAV_1MG.wav", from = 1, to = Inf, units = c("seconds"), header = FALSE, toWaveMC = NULL)
head(wave_file)
mono_file <- mono(wave_file, which = c("both"))
head(mono_file)
auto_file <- autodetec(X = "C:/Users/ABC/Downloads/file_example_WAV_1MG.wav")
head(auto_file)
dataframe <- data.frame(list = c("sound.files", "selec", "start", "end"))
dataframe <- data.frame(wave_file, "abc", 1, Inf)
dataframe

# Existing Example found in R docs
#setwd('C:/Users/ABC/Downloads')
#data1 <- data(list = c("Phae.long1", "Phae.long2", "Phae.long3", "Phae.long4", "selec.table"))
#writeWave(Phae.long1,"Phae.long1.wav")
#writeWave(Phae.long2,"Phae.long2.wav")
#writeWave(Phae.long3,"Phae.long3.wav")
#writeWave(Phae.long4,"Phae.long4.wav")
#writeWave(Phae.long1,"file_example_WAV_1MG.wav")
#writeWave(Phae.long2," ")
#writeWave(Phae.long3,"1")
#writeWave(Phae.long4,"Inf")

getwd()


#file <- specan(X = selec.table, bp = c(0, 22))
#head(file)

file <- specan(X = dataframe, bp = c(0,22))
```

How to give my own `.wav` file as argument to the `specan` function?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of passing the actual wav file to the dataframe, pass the name of that file. So your code should look like this;

```
dataframe <- data.frame(list = c("sound.files", "selec", "start", "end"))

dataframe <- data.frame("file_example_WAV_1MG.wav", 2, 1, 20)

names(dataframe) <- c("sound.files", "selec", "start", "end")

a <- specan(X=dataframe, bp=c(0,22))
```

You can then view `a`. The extracted features will be stored in the dataframe. Make sure your file is stored in the working directory.